# Java, IntelliJ IDEA setup question?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellisense

I was wondering how would I set [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) up to when I click run\debug, it executes an external jar file?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not debugging an application you are developing? You can setup a Remote Debug.  i.e. run the external jar, externally with debug options and attach to it with IntelliJ.  Unless you have the source it will be more difficult.

Answer (score 5):

Add the jar to the [dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html), specify the main class to run.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would probably be to add the jar as a dependency/library of a project, then create a run configuration (Run -> Edit configurations) to run the class you're interested in.